# Late Answers count every click on "review answer", even if it's not reviewed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, late-answers

I was just going quickly through Late Answers to see if I can improve/fix some of them.
I edited a very small amount of answers and opened many.

When I took a look at the sidebar statistics, I saw that I "reviewed" more than 300 answers only today, but I didn't.

So, when you click "review answer" and do nothing, it counts it as reviewed.

Comment: This will be converted to the new system a la First Posts very soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for the old review system. That system counted it as a review as soon as you clicked the *"review [quesiton/answer]"* button below the post. Whether you took action on it (or even looked at it further than that) or not made no difference. Eventually, it will be replaced with a new review task which will follow the newer format for the tasks above it (apparently very soon according to David in the comments above).

Comment: Does this mean that the old engine (*Review first answer\question*) is now abandoned (deprecated) and never again will it work?

Comment: @AlexK: Many of the queues can still be accessed the [manual way](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers), but once they push these new tasks out of beta, the older ones will no longer be available at all. So yes, you can say they are "deprecated" in some sense of the word.